# Microsoft Photo Editor | Conversion | File Signatures

Tags: c#, image, ms-access, image-processing, image-conversion

I'm working on extracting images that were saved in an access database. Some were saved as `Bitmap Image`, some where saved as `Microsoft Photo Editor` (which shows up as MSPhotoEd.3). For each record containing bitmap images I'm obtaining the hexidecimal data that is saved and using the file signatures to obtain the image data and converting to binary. This works perfectly and as expected.

I'm currently attempting to do the same thing for the `Microsoft Photo Editor` images, however I'm having a difficult time finding documentation as to how this file format is structured. I'm going through the hex and I see signatures that would correlate to a jpeg file, however there are several of them (3 markers FFD8FF) and they do not coincide with eachother (22 trailers FFD9). It could be that this format is completely different and those just happen to show up...I'm not sure.

Has anyone attempted to do this before? Is it possible to extract a jpeg image from this file format (`Microsoft Photo Editor`)? If not does anyone know what the best way would be to go about converting this file format to any other usable image format programmatically?

Comment: Same for me, I've managed to work out the file formats using the file magic numbers... but for MSPhotoEd3, Im wordering if there's a proprietary format...

Comment: possible solution, but never got it to work... http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm

Comment: Same requirement.. Was there any luck in extracting image from MSPhotoEd.3 files?

Comment: @Faisal I WAS! However I'm afraid that once I had completed the process I deleted everything from my system (as the database contained a lot of PII) including what I used to accomplish this. I remember downloading an access database that someone had configured to work with a custom .dll file that was able to convert this file format. I apologize for not posting the solution when it was discovered. You might try the link given in the above comment by `Joe DF`, as that MIGHT have been what I used but I'm not certain.